# shifting string to left

Tags: c#

We have a string: `0000029653`. How to shift numbers by some value.
For example, shift by 4 then result must be :`0296530000`
There is operator or function for this?
Thanks

Comment: And what should be the result when you shift the example by 6 ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: the result must be: 6530000029

Comment: FYI: That's called rotating, not shifting.

Comment: And '6530000029' looks more like a rotate of 7.

Answer (score 4):

You could convert it to an number then do this:

```
Result = yournumber * Math.Pow(10, shiftleftby);
```

then convert it back to string and pad left with 0s

Comment: did you saw 0000 in the beginning of number? It will not work

Comment: It won't work because when you store a number in an int, the starting 0's are ignored, because they do not mean anything. If i do int num = 00001; num will hold 1, not 00001. This answer casts your string to an int (which will lose the 0's infront before doing any of the math operations).

Comment: Yes, that was why I suggested putting them back by padding to the left to the full width

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use substring and indexes, you can also play with Linq :

```
string inString = "0000029653";
var result = String.Concat(inString.Skip(4).Concat(inString.Take(4)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public string Shift(string numberStr, int shiftVal)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        int i = numberStr.Length;
        char[] ch = numberStr.ToCharArray();
        for (int j = shiftVal; result.Length < i; j++)
            result += ch[j % i];

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: There's no need to make a copy as a char array - characters in a string can be accessed by indexing the string directly (i.e. `numberStr[j % i]` would work).

Answer (score 0):

You could cast your numbers as ints to strings and back.

```
String number = "0000029653";
String shiftedNumber = number.Substring(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below methods take the number n which tells how many times you want to shift/rotate the string. I have taken the MOD by length of string if the number is greater than the length of string.

```
public static void Rotate(ref string str, int n)
    {
        if (n < 1)
            throw new Exception("Negative number for rotation"); ;
        if (str.Length < 1) throw new Exception("0 length string");

        if (n > str.Length) // If number is greater than the length of the string then take MOD of the number
        {
            n = n % str.Length;
        }

        StringBuilder s1=new StringBuilder(str.Substring(n,(str.Length - n)));
        s1.Append(str.Substring(0,n));
        str=s1.ToString();


    }

///You can make a use of Skip and Take functions of the String operations
     public static void Rotate1(ref string str, int n)
    {
        if (n < 1)
            throw new Exception("Negative number for rotation"); ;
        if (str.Length < 1) throw new Exception("0 length string");

        if (n > str.Length)
        {
            n = n % str.Length;
        }

        str = String.Concat(str.Skip(n).Concat(str.Take(n)));

    }
```